# My Code for Implementation of Stack which is written in Code Blocks is Compiling successfully but shows error during Run time

Tags: c, data-structures, ide, stack, codeblocks

I have enclosed the screenshots of run time errors.

This code will create a stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 5         
// Declared a Structure with top,an array as its members

     struct Stack {  
     int items[SIZE],top;  

     };


//push method inserts an element in the stack

void push(struct Stack *s1,int x){   
    s1->items[++s1->top]=x;
}

// pop  method is for Removing the Elements

void pop(struct Stack* s1){  
    printf("Before pop the Top is %d ",s1->top);
    int a=s1->items[s1->top--];
    printf("After pop the Top is %d",s1->top);
}


//Main method


void main() {
    struct Stack s,*s1;
    struct Stack top = {-1};    //Initializing Top variable in Structure 
    int n;

    //loop to insert the elements

     for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
     printf("Enter the elements to be pushed");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     push( s1, n);
      }
    pop(s1);
    pop(s1);

    printf("The Elements of the Stack after performing all the operations are   ");

    // Print the elements of the stack

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {  
     printf("%d",s1->items[SIZE]); 

    }

}
```

Comment: You should debug your code and add the output to your question.

Comment: Please, show us the stack elements you used to test your program and the "error" output

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues:

This is a corrected version of your program. All corrections are commented.
The code is still sloppy (e.g. there is no error checking, variable names are meaningless) but at least it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 5         

struct Stack {
  int items[SIZE];
  int top;             // better readability
};


// push method inserts an element in the stack

void push(struct Stack *s1, int x) {
  s1->items[++s1->top] = x;
}

// pop  method is for removing ONE Element  // COMMENT CORRECTED

int pop(struct Stack* s1) {   // we need to return the popped element
  printf("Before pop the Top is %d\n", s1->top);
  int a = s1->items[s1->top--];
  printf("After pop the Top is %d\n", s1->top);
  return a;
}


int main() {        // main must return an int
  struct Stack s;   // removed useless s1 ansd top variables
                    // BTW s1 was an uninitialized pointer so this was
                    // totally wrong
  int n;

  s.top = -1;       // initialize top correctly 
                    // struct Stack s = {-1}  will not initialize s.top !!

  for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    printf("Enter the elements to be pushed: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    push(&s, n);
  }

  printf("First popped value: %d\n", pop(&s));   // print popped elements
  printf("Second popped value: %d\n", pop(&s));

  printf("The Elements of the Stack after performing all the operations are: ");

  for (int i = 0; i <= s.top; i++) {   //i <= top instead of i < SIZE
    printf("%d\n", s.items[i]);        // s.items[i] instead of s.items[SIZE]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will point out some of the major problems in your code.
Please take care of these when programming.

push() and pop() method seems to be OK.

Your program complies successfully because it doesn't have any syntax error.
Runtime errors such as things due to memory management, logical errors etc cannot be identified by compiler. Hence getting a code compiled means you don't have the right answer. You need to debug each and every line with prints or something to trace how much your program works before it crash.

In this program you get segmentation fault due to memory management issue.
Because here you use pointer s1 as argument to push() and pop() functions.
But your pointer s1 is not initialized with a struct Stack variable. As such s1 points to arbitrary memory location and modifying data at that memory location is not allowed and causes segmentation fault.

You can see this has been rectified in the code given as answer by @Michael Walz.

```
struct Stack s;     //This variable is statically allocated and has enough memory
struct Stack *s1;   //Pointer variable stores only address of the struct no memory
                    //for struct is allocated. Dynamic allocation is required
```

Allocation of memory to pointer variable s1 can be done in following ways.

```
//Dyanmic memory allocation from heap
s1 = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
```

Or assign an address of an already allocated variable like

```
struct Stack s, *s1;
s1=&s;
```

Now s1 will be pointing to a valid struct Stack object and hence segmentation fault due to referring to a forbidden memory location can be avoided.

The following code you wrote doesn't actually initialize top variable in a struct

```
struct Stack top = {-1};
```

This creates an another Stack struct with name top and the first element in the array item[] as -1.

To access element of struct as follows

```
struct Stack s;
struct Stack *s1; 
s.top = -1;      //Statically allocated. Referencing by '.'
s1->top = -1;    //Referencing by '->' for pointers
```

**Note:**
A good link suggesting how struct initialization can be done. Many different possibilities are mentioned in this link. Good to have a look.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization